# Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\langle \operatorname{erfc}(-nx), \phi\rangle =\langle H_0, \phi\rangle $

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, distribution-theory

Define the error function $\operatorname{erf}(x)$ as:

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{erf}(x):=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-y^2}dy
\end{equation}
and $\operatorname{erfc}(x):=1-\operatorname{erf}(x)$. Now, I would like to prove that the limit of the sequence of distributions which are defined from the sequence of functions:
\begin{equation}
f_n(x):=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erfc}(-nx)
\end{equation}
is the Heaviside distribution, i.e: $f_n \to H_0$ *(in the way that convergence is defined in $\mathcal{D}'$).*

I played around a bit with the integrals but I had no luck.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Hints: You may notice the following facts:

$$
\text{erf}(-x)=-\text{erf}(x),\\
\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty }\text{erf}(x)=1
$$

Therfore:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty }1-\text{erf}(x)=1-\text{sign}(x)
$$

Can you take it from here?

Edit:

Another way to prove this would be to use the following representation of the $\delta$-distribution

$$\delta(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}e^{-n x^2}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

And the fact that $\int_0^x\delta(x')dx'=H(x)$

Comment: Well, I am not familiar with that representation of $\delta$.. Even though  it looks that it makes everything simpler. But on the first suggestion you made, I suspect that at a point I should take the limit while $x\to \infty$? Because what I must show is what happens when $n \to \infty$ and not $x$. In any case, it is quite difficult for me to see how to prove that, at least at the level which I am right now, so your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: take $x=qn$ with $q$ fixed :) in my second formula and take the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$ instead \

Comment: Oh ok. I will try it and come back later. I think that I may find out the way after all :P

Comment: good. if you would like to go the way of my second suggestion, it is not too difficult to prove that this is representation of dirac's delta...